# Why is CASE WHEN acting backwards in this query?

Tags: mysql, case, sql-like

I'm trying to use CASE WHEN to group multiple possible values in a SQL view. It works, but backwards and I'd like to understand why.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    name,
    CASE
        WHEN name NOT LIKE '%Value1%' THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN name NOT LIKE '%Value2%' THEN 'Group2'
        WHEN name NOT LIKE '%Value3%' THEN 'Group3'
        ELSE name
    END AS 'filtered name'
FROM sometable;
```

This actually gives me the output that I need:

- Anything that contains Value1 is put in Group1
- Anything that contains Value2 is put in Group2
- Anything that contains Value3 is put in Group3
- Anything else keeps it's current name

Now, I expected the query for this result to be the one I currently have without any 'NOT' before the 'LIKE' operators, and I am quite confused that this works, I am trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: Can you give an example of your dataset?

Comment: *Anything that contains Value1 is put in Group1* how? Anything that contains Value1 will fail `WHEN name NOT LIKE '%Value1%' THEN 'Group1'`.